# Using vector as an argument in STL map

Tags: c++, vector, stl, containers, stdmap

I've been trying to link 2 values with 1 key and one of the ways I found was using a vector to do the same. I wrote the following code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std; 

map<int,vector<int> map1;

void insertInMap(int q,int a,int b)
{
    vector<int> v1;
    v1.push_back(a);
    v1.push_back(b);
    map1.insert(q,v1);
}
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The insertinmap function is to create a vector as an argument for the map. I'm getting an error where I'm initializing the list

Error - template 2 argument is invalid , template 4 argument is invalid.

Comment: `map<int,vector<int> map1;` shoulld be `map<int,vector<int>> map1;`

Comment: You could use `std::pair` for insert like `map1.insert(std::pair<int, vector<int>>(q, v1));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a map, [`insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) expects as argument one element to insert.  The element of a map is a pair made of the key and the value.  So:

```
map1.insert(make_pair(q,v1));
```

A more convenient way to insert elements in the map is to use the assignement operator in combination with indexing:

```
map1[q] = v1;
```

***Note:***  you've forgotten a closing `>` in the definition of your map, but I guess it's a typo

Comment: Or `map1.emplace(q, v1);`

Comment: @Galik indeed !

Comment: @Jejo If the vector will always be only 2 elements, then the pair is definitively a better alternative.  In my answer I wanted to stay focused on the specific usage of insert() that blocked the OP.